Partition of $d-1$-dimensional unit sphere into disjoint small diameter sets?
Is there a sensible constructive way to finitely partition the $d-1$-dimensional unit sphere  $\mathbb{S}^{d-1} \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ into Borel measurable sets with small diameter?
As an explicit simple example, consider $d = 2$. The $1$-dimensional unit sphere can be dyadically partitioned as follows
$$ \mathbb{S}^1 = \bigcup_{k=0}^{2^n - 1} \left\{(\cos \theta, \sin \theta) : \theta \in 2 \pi \left[ \frac{k}{2^n}, \frac{k+1}{2^n}\right) \right\} .$$
The sets in the union are disjoint Borel measurable, and by increasing $n$, their diameters can be made arbitrarily small.
However, it is unclear to me how to do a similar construction for higher dimensions.

I would start with a Regular Polytope, then subdivide the facets in some kind of regular way until they are small. Note that for any polytope inscribed in an $(n-1)$-sphere, you can associate it to a partition of that sphere by projecting the facets onto the sphere (so long as the projection is injective, which is the "typical" case).
Here are two concrete approaches:

Start with the regular n-simplex inscribed in the sphere, then use repeated barycentric subdivision to make its projected partitions as small as you want.

Start with the $n$-dimensional hypercube, then subdivide each of its ($n-1$)-dimensional facets into $2^{n-1}$ subfacets by dividing along the coordinate hyperplanes (that is, hyperplanes $H \subset \mathbb{R} = \{x_1,...x_n | x_i = 0\}$ for a particular $i$). Repeat this style of division on each subfacet until the projections to the sphere are as small as you want.



There are only five regular polytopes in three dimensions, six in four dimensions, and three in all higher dimensions, so I don't think they would do much good anyway.

@BrianTung I didn't mean the regular polytopes provide an answer directly, but rather serve as a starting point. I've edited the first two paragraphs to make that clearer. There may be "more regular" approaches by using discrete subgroups of the rotation group, but I'm not familiar enough with that group to give a good constructive example in arbitrary dimensions.

Finite subgroups of the orthogonal group are not helpful for solving such problems, barycentric subdivisions are  the most standard solution.

@MartianInvader Got it!
